# Need help to retrieve an array of elements with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone help me retrieve several elements from a website.
This is the website: http://www.androidpolice.com/tags/series_android_n_feature_spotlights/

It shows all articles with the tag Android N Feature Spotlight
I want to get all the titles of the articles. The titles are contained inside  tags with the class .post-header and the titles are inside header.post-header -> h2 -> a.text.

I know I need to start with getElementsByTagName('header') but I don't know how to carry on. Any help is appreciated.

Solved thanks to @EvaMariam
jQuery('header.post-header').find('h2').children('a').text();

Comment: It's a third-party website? [Not possible with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Hi, I donot about javascript..i am new to jquery.. got it using jQuery('header.post-header').find('h2').children('a').text();  .. is this what you are looking for??

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @EvaMariam that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not about javascript..i am new to jquery.. Got it using

> jQuery('header.post-header').find('h2').children('a').text();

You can use find() and children() in jquery to get the h2 tags inside header tag with class post-header and filter the h2 having a tag as children.

Comment: That worked, thank you Eva!